# Macbook air SSD connection to PC

Tags: mac, ssd, connector

I wonder if the SSD with the connector shows below can be plugged it into my PC.

[image]

Comment: @Hennes I disagree with you editing out the link, that was useful to identify the drive.

Comment: For future reference, a bit more information would be appreciated. Things like what is the make and model of the SSD in question? What is your "PC"? A laptop? A tower? Running Windows? Linux? OSX? PC is usually not used for Macs but you have tagged this question with the Mac tag. I _guess_ this is a MacBook Air's SSD but it would be nice to _know_.

Comment: Well basicly I can connect it to a Mac or a PC, I just need to connect the MBA's memory to the machine

Comment: @issac There's actually a much easier solution to your problem if you have another mac with Thunderbolt and a cable: Target disk mode (http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725).

Comment: The keyboard/screen doesn't work they're all broke. The only incentive I have that it actually works is the noise it makes when it loads up.

Comment: As long as you have the T key working and it boots, to my knowledge target disk should work, but I have an ancient mac so I haven't tried

Answer (score 2):

Apple uses their own non-standard connectors for SSDs for some reason, so it won't work unless someone out there is making an adapter for them, which I doubt there is.

Comment: Only one company as far as I can tell is making the enclosures, but it's out of my price range including shipping and everything.

Comment: There are a few more [for example](http://www.amazon.com/inch-Adapter-Macbook-Version-Retina/dp/B00A77B9TC/); the only issue is finding what works

Answer (score 0):

The OCZ Envoy enclosure you linked to can use a MBA drive as external storage for a PC, but the connector is custom-designed by Apple, so it won't fit **inside** your PC, sorry.

Comment: That's a tiny bit out of my budget, surely there's one avalible on the market

Comment: Are you looking to connect a drive you already have? If so, http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/MAU3ENVOY12/ comes without a drive. Do make sure it;s a 2012 drive instead of 2011, though.

Comment: Or are you looking to buy an entire external SSD? In which case there are much cheaper options.

Comment: I'm just looking to connect that to my PC to extract some files because my current MBA screen is broken, I have some pictures that weren't backed up so I NEED some how to get the files

Comment: Thank's, at the moment I'm looking at all the possibilities at the moment.

Comment: Wait, I lied, there may be more that I haven't heard of, check Google (I am).

Comment: Could you post what you are searching for?

Comment: I just Googled "macbook air ssd enclosure -owc" (I'll delete this comment when I've done more research and probably edit my answer, but I don't have time now, sorry)